# How to customize the titlebar of a QMdiSubWindow with qss?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, mdichild

I'd like to customize the titlebar of a QMdiSubWindow.
For that I use a qss.

```
QMdiSubWindow { border: 1px solid #000000; background: #000000 }
QMdiSubWindow:title { background: #000000 }
```

The problem is when applying this qss, the window icons disappear.
I know it's possible to define these icons in qss for a QDockWidget

```
QDockWidget { ... titlebar-close-icon: url(myCloseIcon.png); ... }
```

However I can't find a way to define it for a QMdiSubWindow.
Perhaps this way doesn't exists.
Do you know if it's possible ?

Comment: This is an issue for many years now. Are there any workarounds to style MDI childs?

Answer (score 2):

As of `Qt 5.2` you can't; haven't checked `5.3` but AFAIK they didn't changed anything in the `QMdiArea/QMdiSubWindow` in the `5.3` release.

The easiest solution you have is to use `QCommonStyle` and paint the title bar using `QPainter`. For more info on that see the [QCommonStyle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcommonstyle.html) and [QStyle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyle.html) documentations. Please note that it is recommended to derive `QCommonStyle` and not `QStyle` for your style class. `QCommonStyle` inherits `QStyle` so you won't loose anything.

And if you want to achieve more complex effects such as drop shadow on the sub window then the only option you have left here is to derive `QMdiSubWindow` and `QMdiArea`, call `QWidget::setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHintflag)` on the `QMdiSubWindow` derived class and implement from scratch your own subwindow with your own title bar. You can then define your own `Q_PROPERTY`s of type `QColor` and access those from `QSS` like exposed [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Style_Sheets_and_Custom_Painting_Example) in order to customize titlebar colors from `QSS`.

Another option would be to create a new MDI area widget from scratch but I don't think this would be applicable in your case. If you just need to customize the title bar using a custom style is the best approach you can tackle. If in trouble examples could be provided as an edit to this post.

But if you want to customize the standard `QMdiSubWindow` using just `QSS`, unfortunately it is not possible for the moment.